# Why does heterogenous version of erase for associative containers take in forwarding reference?

Tags: c++, language-design, c++23

Is there any particular reason why heterogeneous version of `erase` in associative containers (`std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, `std::multimap` and `std::unordered_multimap`) takes in a forwarding reference and all other heterogeneous functions  (`find`/`equal_range`, `count`, `contains`) take in const-reference?

For instance in case of `std::unordered_map`:

```cpp
template<class K> iterator find(const K& k);
template<class K> const_iterator find(const K& k) const;
template<class K> size_type erase(K&& x);
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase (overload 4)
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find (overloads 3/4)

Section 24.5.4.1 of (lastest working draft) [n4910](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/n4910.pdf)

(This, as mentioned, applies to other containers as well.)

Comment: You may want `language-design` tag, since the question is in regard to C++ language design rationale.

Comment: I've found the answer. Original proposal p2077r3 explains it. 
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2077r3.html

Comment: Consider self answering with a summary of or quote from the link. I you wondered about this sooner or later someone else will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a bit more research I've found the original proposal [p2077](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2077r3.html) which explains it (paragraphs 2 and 3.1).

If the overload

```cpp
template <class K>
size_type erase( const K& x );
```

existed, it would be chosen when passing an object of a type, which is implicitly convertible to either `iterator` or `const_iterator` and that is not what users might expect.

Additionally it is not possible to create a valid constraints for the mentioned overload because the value category of `K` is lost due to template argument deduction from `const K&` function parameter. Therefore, we cannot define constraints over `K` for the arbitrary case. To propagate the information about the value category of `K` we define the function parameter for heterogeneous erasure as forwarding reference.

A more detailed explanation can be found in proposal.